# Is a mutable object still constant

Tags: java, constants

If i have an object lets say for example

```
public class Person {

    private int age;

    public Person(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

and

```
public static final Person PERSON = new Person(12);
```

Because I still can change the age is it not considered constant?

Comment: see this link Click [declaring object as final in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260102/declaring-object-as-final-in-java")!

Comment: just remove the setter method and make `age` as `final` variable

Answer (score 5):

> Because I still can change the age is it not considered constant?

`PERSON` is "constant" in that it will always point to the *same* `Person` instance. The `Person` instance to which it does point, however, is not constant since it can be mutated. This is more a matter of terminology than anything.

Comment: @ErikMadsen Again, I think this is really a question of terminology without a meaningful answer. I've edited slightly to clarify what I mean.

Answer (score 3):

It's reference that is `final`(constant) but still you can update its state (instance variable) but you can't assign it to other Person object.

It's better explanaied under [JLS - 4.12.4. final Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4)

> Once a final variable has been assigned, it always contains the same value.
>
> If a final variable holds a `reference` to an object, then the state of the object may be changed by operations on the object, but the variable will always refer to the same object.

You can't say

```
person = new Person(20);
```

Comment: What's the difference you're trying to show between primitives and reference types?

Comment: Why it's not possible to assign value again in case of primitive but possible with object?

Comment: It's impossible with both primitives *and* objects.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not possible to assign value again in case of primitive but possible with object"? Assigning value is different than manipulate its state.

Comment: @Pshemo deleted primitive and string part to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as in real life. The PERSON you created is a concrete person. You can label it using **PERSON**, **user2896769** or using some unique [ID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_identification_number). When you reference the object by this label you always reference the same object (because it's final) but the object itself can change (like people in reality can get older, so their age changes).

So `final` means that the reference is constant, not that the object itself is **immutable**.
If you want your PERSON not to change at all, then the reference has to be `final` and the object that the reference is pointing to has to be [immutable](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=29).

When you write:

```
public static final Person PERSON = new Person(12);
```

It means that from now on PERSON will reference the newly created person object. It **does not mean** that the PERSON **is** the newly created person object. Again - **it means that it references** (points to) the object. So that you have a reference to an object. And this reference is final, constant, always points to the same object. But the object itself can change as long as it's mutable.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's a matter of semantics whether PERSON is constant, but it is not considered to be "a constant", but rather a final object reference.

In addition I would have chosen normal lowercase naming for the variable. There's an excellent discussion of that in [this question](/questions/1417190/should-a-static-final-logger-be-declared-in-upper-case).

One of the answers in said question quotes Effective Java, 2nd edition for the following criteria for a field being constant:

> A constant field is a static final field whose value is immutable. If
>   a static final field has a primitive type or an immutable reference
>   type (...), then it is a constant field.